# Conditional sections in Pandoc markdown

Tags: pandoc

I want some sections of my document to be only for a given output format. For instance, I have an image that requires special LaTeX treatment and i want to use \includegraphics for it. But for the epub version, I want the standard behavior.

Is there a way in Pandoc markdown to specify a section that should be processed only in a given context (LaTex vs epub). Templates have conditionals. I did not see the feature for Pandoc markdown.

Or is there another way of dealing with this use case?

Comment: `echo '![](img.jpg)' | pandoc -t latex` already outputs `\includegraphics` etc, right?

Comment: Yes, but how do I pass some parameters to \includegraphics, e.g. to modify size, from the markdown?

Comment: Better suited for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with the file preprocessor [filepp](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~dm26/filepp/). We define a function `img(caption,path,options)` that is replaced by `![caption](path)` or by `\includegraphics` depending on a flag. Notice two things: you need to escape commas in the function arguments (see the third argument of the first plot); you need to have two unescaped commas, even if one argument is not specified (see the second example plot below).

test.md

```
#bigfunc img(caption,path,options)
#if "out_fmt" eq "tex"
\begin{figure}
   \caption{\label{caption} caption}
   \includegraphics[options]{path}
\end{figure}
#else
![caption](path)
#endif
#endbigfunc

Here is an image

img(Plot,Rplot.png,height=2\,width=2)
img(Plot,Rplot.png,)
```

We specify the ouput format in the filepp command and pipe it through pandoc:

```
filepp -m bigfunc.pm -D out_fmt=tex test.md | pandoc -o test.tex
filepp -m bigfunc.pm -D out_fmt=html test.md | pandoc -o test.html
```

tex output:

```
Here is an image

\begin{figure}
   \Plot{\label{Plot} Plot}
   \includegraphics[height=2,width=2]{Rplot.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
   \Plot{\label{Plot} Plot}
   \includegraphics[]{Rplot.png}
\end{figure}
```

html output:

```
<p>Here is an image</p>
<div class="figure">
<img src="Rplot.png" alt="Plot" />
<p class="caption">Plot</p>
</div>
<div class="figure">
<img src="Rplot.png" alt="Plot" />
<p class="caption">Plot</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possibilities:

- Write a custom filter, that modifies the document's AST, see [pandoc scripting](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html).
- Use a preprocessor, see this [post about using gpp in front of pandoc](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/markdown-with-gpp/).
- In limited use cases you can use `\renewcommand` in your LaTeX template to change the behavior of a LaTeX command.

Comment: I managed to make it work using gpp, by adding the following lines in my markdown file
`\ifdef{TEX} ...` and 
`\ifdef{EPUB} ...`
Then you can use `gpp -T -DTEX` of `gpp -T -DEPUB`.

But this is not valid markdown anymore. When I `pandoc` it, it complains that \ifdef is not defined. Any way to make the gpp preprocessing commands be markdown friendly?

Comment: The idea is to first run gdp which processes the `<#ifdef TEX>...<#endif>` and generates valid markdown that doesn't contain them anymore. then run pandoc on that.